# Find first and last of a unique element in a column

Tags: arrays, element, tail, head

In a data table such as with the following format:

```
id  Time 1  Time2   V1  V2
1   1       10      30  40
1   2       20      31  41
1   3       30      32  42
1   4       40      33  43
2   1       10      40  50
2   2       20      41  51
2   3       30      42  52
2   4       40      43  53
3   1       10      50  60
3   2       20      51  61
3   3       30      52  62
3   4       40      53  63
```

I want to select the two smallest and two largest variable readings of time 1 and time 2

I want to do a regression and correlation analysis of v1 and v2 using the first two and last two time readings for each unique ID

Thanks

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: So what have you tried?  And as above, with what were you looking to solve your problem?  If you need a suggestion, it has columns so awk would be a good start

Comment: Thanks Tim Biegelesen, I am using R Studio.  I was thinking of using the unique and head functions.  Something like this...IDList <- sort(unique(d1$StudyID))
for(i in StudyIDList) 
{d2 <- subset(d1, d1$StudyID == i) 
Reg1<-lm(head,(IDList[i]),v1~v2, data = d2 )}